# How to ingest property value to cpack-wix without need for running cmake again?

Tags: cmake, properties, wix, cpack

I am using `cmake` and `cpack` and `wix` to build and deploy my project. The installer has some properties that user can enter via GUI or MSI-command-line options.
I set default property values in my `CMakeLists.txt` using:

```
set(CPACK_WIX_PROPERTY_<PROPERTY> <value>)
```

The problem is that if I change these values, I should rerun `cmake` command before `cpack` command.

I am looking for a way to change default value of these properties without need for rerunning `cmake`.

I tried adding additional `wxs` files using `CPACK_WIX_EXTRA_SOURCES` or patching generated files with additional `xml` files using `CPACK_WIX_PATCH_FILE`, but couldn't find the right code to put in `wxs` or `xml` files to accomplish my goal.

I tried The `SetProperty` command and found out its behavior is not easy to control, I gave up when I saw the user provided values don't replace the initial values and suggested solution at https://web.archive.org/web/20180205001358/http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Unable-to-override-SetProperty-value-with-Edit-Control-value-td7591569.html didn't work. I hope there is a simple way, but even a complex answer using `SetProperty` is allright.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, your solution works exactly as expected. Can you please write this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for a way to change default value of these properties without need for rerunning `cmake`.

A script specified in [CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html#variable:CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE) variable is the one, which affects on CPack, but which changing doesn't require `cmake` to re-run. So you may place setting of `CPACK_WIX_PROPERTY_<PROPERTY>` here: Changing this setting would require only to re-run CPack without re-run `cmake` on the main project.

---

Also, when the script specified in `CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE` variable is parsed, `CPACK_GENERATOR` variable contains the exact CPack generator which is currently processed. This opposites to behavior of the variable inside `CMakeLists.txt`, when it contains a *list* of generators.